# datetime field in django is being displayed differently in the template and not like the saved one in database

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

The following is a part of my ajax request in my django template

```
<span class='time-left'>${response.chats[key].date}</span></div>`;
```

This is the model field it is refering to...

```
date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True, blank=True)
```

Now this is the problem. The datetime is saved correctly in the database to my current timezone. However, when I display it in the template like above, I get a different time for some reason. the `USE_TZ=True` in my settings, and I don't want to change it. Do you know how I could show the saved value in the database in the template as well?

Answer (score 0):

The behavior you're observing is related to how Django handles time zones. When `USE_TZ` is set to `True`, Django stores date and time information in the database in UTC. When retrieving this data to show in templates, Django converts it to the current time zone of the user, or the default time zone you've set in your settings (`TIME_ZONE`).

If you want to display the saved UTC value in your template, you'll need to convert it back to UTC when sending it via AJAX.

Here's a way to do it:

1. **Modify your Django View**: When you prepare the response for your AJAX call, ensure the date is in UTC. You can do this using Django's `timezone` utilities:

```py
from django.utils import timezone

# ... your code ...

chat_date = response.chats[key].date
utc_date = timezone.localtime(chat_date, timezone=timezone.utc)

# Then send this utc_date in your response
```

2. **Modify your JavaScript**: Now, when you receive the date in your AJAX response, it'll be in UTC. Display it directly in your template:

```js
<span class='time-left'>${response.chats[key].utc_date}</span></div>`;
```

This will show the date and time in the UTC time zone, which is how it's saved in the database.

Remember, by doing this, you're overriding Django's default behavior, which is meant to show dates and times in a user's local time zone (or the server's default time zone if not set). Ensure that this behavior aligns with the expectations of your users. If you want to show users their local times, stick with Django's default behavior. If, however, you want to show the exact time something happened on the server (in server's time), then this approach works.

Comment: This doesn't work. Also, it seems ai generated... Can you recheck your code?

Comment: I don't know but the above example works for me when I modify my defined Django View. Also what is so AI about my response? There is another more simple way. If you are OK with **always** displaying the time in UTC by default in templates then just set TIME_ZONE = 'UTC' in settings.py.